# Is it possible to add custom lookup field to Google Contacts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-contacts-api

Our company uses Google Apps. I'd like to manage all our customers in Google Contacts. Can I add organizations and individuals as separate contacts and then link them via custom lookup field?

Comment: Did you find a way to do it ? I would like to assign an Organization to a contact, using Gdata.

Answer (score -2):

There are many options that you can do to easily manage your contacts like organize, review and even merge contacts. Everything that you can do with contacts are explained step by step in [Google Apps Learning Center](https://apps.google.com/learning-center/products/contacts/get-started/#section-1).